# Comparing DNA sequences in Python 3

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.x

My program so far is:

```
seq_a = "TGGAGGCAATGGCGGCCAGCA"
seq_b = "GACTCCTCCTCCTCCTGCTCA"    
len_a = len(seq_a)    
len_b = len(seq_b)    
print("Length of Sequence A: " + str(len_a))    
print()    
print("Length of Sequence B: " + str(len_b))
print()

def sequence_compare(seq_a, seq_b):
        len1 = len(seq_a)
        len2 = len(seq_b)
        mismatches = []
        for pos in range (0, min(len1, len2)) :
              if seq_a[pos] != seq_b[pos]:
                  mismatches.append('|')
              else:
                  mismatches.append(' ')
        print (seq_a)
        print (mismatches)
        print (seq_b)
sequence_compare(seq_a,seq_b)
```

I expect an output along the lines of:

```
TGGAGGCAATGGCGGCCAGCA
||||||||| |||||||||
GACTCCTCCTCCTCCTGCTCA
```

But instead the output is:

```
TGGAGGCAATGGCGGCCAGCA
['|', '|', '|', '|', '|', '|', '|', '|', '|', ' ', '|', '|', '|', '|', '|', '|', '|', '|', '|', ' ', ' ']
GACTCCTCCTCCTCCTGCTCA
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are quite near..

```
print ("".join(mismatches))
```

will do the trick and print as required which is

```
||||||||| |||||||||
```

Comment: Thanks man that worked super! Not sure why though, still learning Python 3

Comment: All it does is say, "Take the list of mismatch characters in order and join them to be a single string, separated by nothing." If you had done `",".join(mismatches)` you'd have gotten the same output with comma separation instead of squished together.